# How to set more directions for UISwipeGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, directions, uiswipegesturerecognizer

`UISwipeGestureRecognizer` has four directions that I can set: up, down, right, left.

but as I tried to set, the direction of a swipe seems need to be quite precise. I mean, for example, if I set a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` with toUp direction, and if I swipe my finger not that precise toUp, say 45 degree in the middle of up and right, the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` can't get it.

But I noticed that for `UIScrollView`, it is not the case.

So How can I give more directions for `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` or how can I make the direction check more relax?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to use Apple's swipe gesture to be consistent with their Apps.  You could try defining your own by subclassing the UISwipeGestureRecognizer, or creating your own class using the older UITouchesBegan, UITouchesEnded, etc methods.